# How to select List in a List by Key through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list

I originally have 2 Lists for Keynotes and Tracks. Each of which were then Grouped By date through a Key. See below:

```
var Keynotes = _keynoteService.GetKeynotesForContentItem(trackPart.ContentItem).GroupBy(k => string.Format("{0}-{1}", k.Timeslot.DayOfYear, k.Timeslot.Year));
var Tracks = GetTracksForContentItem(trackPart.ContentItem);

foreach (var track in Tracks)
{
     var trackItem = new TrackItem();
     trackItem.Days = new List<TrackDay>();

     var trackDays = track.Sessions.GroupBy(s => string.Format("{0}-{1}", s.Timeslot.DayOfYear, s.Timeslot.Year));

     foreach(var trackDay in trackDays)
     {
          var trackKey = trackDay.Key //THIS IS THE KEY I NEED TO MATCH IN Keynotes
          var trackKeynotes = Keynotes. //I'm Stuck here
```

The new lists are now Keynotes and trackDays which are actually lists of lists by Date Keys.

How do I select a list within Keynotes that matches a specific key from trackDays? I already have the key, I just need to know how to select from Keynotes properly to get the right list.

I'm not a LINQ expert so I'd like some help.

I was thinking Keynotes.Select or Keynotes.SingleOrDefault

Any piece of advise would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Best way is probably to `join` Keynotes and TrackDays on the keys that are common.  http://stackoverflow.com/q/3889741

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var trackKeynotes = Keynotes.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key == trackKey);
```

Comment: He's asking for a list, not a single item.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: it's actually a list because of `GroupBy`

Comment: This is actually the right way. I mentioned that after the Group By, they become lists within lists.
Where, as proposed by many, doesn't select the underlying list so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this

```
var result = (from x in Keynotes
            join td in TrackDays on x.Key equals td.Key
            select x).ToList();
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for this! Really appreciate it.

However, Keynotes and TrackDays have different items (entities), with different columns/properties. Not really sure if joining them together will work but I already tried Cuong's answer. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Use `Keynotes[trackKey]` to index into your grouped items.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead ::

```
var trackKeynotes = Keynotes.Where(K => K.Key == trackKey);
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this

```
var trackKeynotes = Keynotes.Where(x => x.Key == trackKey);
```

I assume that trackKey is a key of Keynotes.