# How do create a join by using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I got this problem. i have this item where i have some images saved on by their index. I want to find all of the images on that item. 
I am new with joins so i am not familiar with the syntax of joins. 
Normally when i recive data unsing Linq i do like this. But when i try to do it like this i cannot recive the data since the data is in different tabels.

```
var item = _db.items.Select(i => i);
```

Comment: by using [Join Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534644(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I just LINQ Join() to link two IQueryables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889741/how-do-i-just-linq-join-to-link-two-iqueryables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different types of joins. But here is a way you could do a regular join.

```
public List<Image> GetImagesInfo(int tradeItemId)
    {
        var query = (from item in _db.ImagesOnTradeItems
                     join image in _db.Images on item.imageId equals image.id
                     where item.tradeItemId == tradeItemId
                     select image);
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

here i return the result as a list after i query through the result.
 Here is a link to a question on joins hope you can use this. [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)